# Java 8 Streaming: Grouping with aggregation

Tags: java, group-by, java-stream, aggregation

I have some trouble finding a good approach/implementation using the Stream API for the following:

I have a list of elements, each element consisting of a string and an integer. Now I like to group the elements by their string values, and then for each group I like to have the sum of the integer values from the elements that relate to that group.

Example: I have the following 3 elements:

```
("GroupA", 100) ("GroupA", 50) ("GroupB", 10)
```

And as a result I like to get a map consisting of the following two (key,value) pairs:

```
("GroupA, 150) ("GroupB, 10)
```

I'm not sure how to solve this. The most promising I came up with so far is this:

```
elements.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e-> e.getGroup()))
            .merge(group, elementsOfTheGroup, (...));
```

But I'm not sure what function to insert as the last parameter of the merge method. But I don't know if I should even use the merge method.

What would be the most elegant implementation for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add a downstream collector to [`Collectors.groupingBy(classifier, downstream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-). This collectors collects all elements that were classified to the same key. In this case, we just need to sum all the numbers together using [`Collectors.summingInt(mapper)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-), with the mapper being a function returning the number to sum.

Assuming this number can be retrieved with the getter `getNumber()`, you could have:

```
Map<String, Integer> result =
    elements.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        e -> e.getGroup(),
        Collectors.summingInt(e -> e.getNumber())
    ));
```

You could use a method-reference instead of the two lambdas above. If the class of the elements is `Element` for example, you would have

```
Map<String, Integer> result =
    elements.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Element::getGroup,
        Collectors.summingInt(Element::getNumber)
    ));
```